# Value of a ListPreference never updates

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences

I have a `ListPreference`, but when I click on an item, the value doesn't update.
The `getValue()` returns always the same thing.

When I reclick on the `ListPreference` the value is unfortunately not changed.

My code :

```
        ListPreference lp7 = (ListPreference) findPreference("paramUpdate");
        lp7.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) preference;
        listPref.getValue();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Preferences xml:

```
    <ListPreference android:key="paramUpdate"
            android:title="@string/paramUpdate"
            android:summary="@string/paramSummaryUpdate"
            android:entries="@array/update"
            android:entryValues="@array/updateValues"
             />
```

Values:

```
<string-array name="update">
    <item>24h</item>
    <item>48h</item>
    <item>72h</item>
    <item>@string/never</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="updateValues">
    <item>24</item>
    <item>48</item>
    <item>72</item>
    <item>0</item>
</string-array>
```

Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to return `true` from your `onPreferenceChangeListener` for the system to store the new value.  See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) for reference.

Comment: Please note that the OnPreferenceChangeListener method onPreferenceChange also provides you with the newValue -> public abstract boolean onPreferenceChange (Preference preference, Object newValue)

Answer (score 2):

Some correctives, if you want to save preference value:

```
 public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) preference;
        int index = listPref.findIndexOfValue((String) newValue);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt("my_pref", index);
        editor.apply();
        return true;
        }
```

Otherwise, ListPreference has updates, but saves from second time.